# Make single table row red (MVC 5/Bootstrap 3)

Tags: jquery, css, sql, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently making a Delete method for my Index View and for my first part of the confirmation I am trying to make a way to turn the current table row red (just so the user can easily see that they selected the right row)

Here is my current view looks
[image]

So when I click delete, I just need a way to temporarily change the row's color to red.

ALSO: Just for background my current content is displaying on odd rows, if I click a item then the next even row will appear to display additional content, so I am not sure if this will interfere with anything.

The way I currently have my Delete working, without any confirmation, is as follows... (all buttons are shown for context)
View snippet

```
<td class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
      <span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID col-lg-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>

      <span class="item-edit-button">
      <button type="button" onclick="editFunction(this)" class=" btn btn-warning col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-0"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
       </span>

       <span class="item-save-button">
                        <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this)" class="btn btn-success col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Save</button>
       </span>

       <span class="item-delete-button">
                        <button type="button" onClick="deleteFunction(this)" class="btn btn-danger col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
       </span>
</td>
```

JQuery snippet (var `newID` just gives me an item's PK in the table)

```
function deleteFunction(element) {
        var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();
        $.post(
                '@Url.Action("customDelete", "Movie")',
                 {
                     'id': newID
                 },
                function (data) { },
                "json"
            );
        $(element).closest("tr").hide();
    }
```

SO I am hoping I can just do some kind of `this.row:background-color = red` for a specified table row, but I am not sure how to do that OR get the current row. (I shall also comment out the AJAX as I will have some kind of confirmation message first)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your delete function you can use the following jQuery

```
$(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'red')
```

I would also use `.remove()` instead of `.hide()`

Comment: that works splendidly. two questions for ya though! 1. my table has the table-responsive attribute which makes everything a default color when a mouse is over it which then un-reds my row, is there an easy fix to this? 2. Would .remove() still work if the content was physically deleted beforehand? (AJAX removes the content before I run the .hide()) Thanks!

Comment: `.hide()` just add `display:none` to the row whereas `.remove` takes it out of the dom and destroys it (which you should do as you are deleting the data).  Not sure about the other thing without seeing what adds the colour to the hover - you may want to post a seperate question for that

Comment: Sounds good, thank you very much! I shall award you the answer once the timer expires